# Experience Builder: Custom Event Types for Menu Item

Tags: lightning-web-components, community, community-builder, experience-cloud

Is it possible to configure custom Events for the `Event` Menu type within the Experience Builder? It currently only gives you three options, `Login`, `Logout` and `Account Switcher`.

This will be paired with a custom header to handle the custom events as needed. I understand adding custom Events would break OOTB navigation components, but this isn't OOTB.

Building out a custom navigation LWC means you need to manually handle the preset events, so I see no harm being able to add custom events.

[image: screenshot of the Menu Editor within the Experience builder]